# Run time error "5" Invalid procedure or call argument

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx

runs perfectly fine on my computer does not run in my wife's, I keep getting the error Run time error "5" Invalid procedure or call argument. Im trying to create a pivot table in a new excel file.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$U$" & lastRow), , xlYes).Name _
    = "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets.Add
***ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Table1", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R3C1", _
    TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=7
Sheets("Sheet2").Select***
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
End With
```

Comment: I'd guess you have a later version of Office. Remove the `, Version:=7` and `, DefaultVersion:=7` parts

Comment: Thank you, im sorry I took your Time, seems so silly now.

Comment: No problem - that's what we're here for. :)